# VS2010 installer project - turning off automatic dependency scan

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation

I inherited an internal product that has a VS2010 installer project.  The internal product is built on top of a much larger COM product that registers most of is COM (dll) via regasm or gacutil.  The problem is VS2010 installer project scans for dependencies, and will add the larger products DLLs, then unregister them on uninstall - breaking both my product and the larger product.

The installer for this internal product unregistering the larger products COM objects has lead to several wasted hours for the team.  I would like to disable VS2010 dependency scan, and provide a static list of dependencies.  I can add dependencies no problem, but cannot figure out how to disable the automatic dependency scan, which keeps re-adding DLLs that do not belong to me, and breaking everything on uninstall.

I cannot change the larger product at all, and do no have the time to re-write the installer in WIX.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the COM wrapper DLLs in a merge module project. The dependency scanner won't scan the referenced merge module. Of course this is assuming your COM wrapper assemblies are static - this is just moving the problem to a less-built project. If you have rapid code changes in there you may want to move the changing part out.